# WPF UserControl Initialized event fireing before notmal properties are set

Tags: .net, wpf, events, user-controls

This is the situation , you can test it for yourselves :
  The microsoft documentation specifies that when the initialized event is fired , all the properties are set (except bindings)
  If you create a new user control and in the code behind file you define a simple string property, then you put this new control on a page and set that property there , when the initialized event is fired on the user control that property will not be set.
  What is the workaround for this except for using the loaded event (cannot do that as I am only creating the controls in memory without displaying them.

Here is the code for the user control :

```
Public Class UserControl1 

Private _Test As String
Public Property test() As String
    Get
        Return _Test
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        _Test = value
    End Set
End Property

Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub

Protected Overrides Sub OnInitialized(ByVal e As System.EventArgs)
    'MyBase.OnInitialized(e)
    Debug.Write(_Test)
End Sub

Private Sub UserControl_Initialized(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Initialized
    Dim parent As FrameworkElement = Me.Parent
    parent = LogicalTreeHelper.GetParent(Me)
End Sub

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering why you comment out `MyBase.OnInitialized(e)`?

What your trying to do is to set a property on a child element via XAML. I believe the MSDN article is saying that properties for the current UserControl (if set in XAML) will be set during the call to InitializeComponent.

InitializeComponent is called during the constructor of the UserControl. The parent element (your page) will have to create the UserControl, and therefore cause the constructor to run, before setting any properties on it.

If you want your child to be notified when a property is set, simply add code to that properties setter.

Another option may be to call a sub on the child after the parent has fully loaded.

Comment: So the OnInitialized comment was just for some tests I tried , it dosen't work with or without the comment.

Comment: About the InitializeComponent there is something else to it ... Indeed it will be called in the UserControl's constructor so all the properties INSIDE the user control's XAML page will be set. But the ones that are set on the page that displays the user control will not. Therefore it would have seemed obvious to me to raise Initialized event after those properties were also set , but that is not what happens. Initialized is indeed called before the constructor of the UserControl exists which means that even code after InitializedComponent in the UserControl's constructor will not be called .

Comment: The suggestion to call a custom initialized sub from the parent is not without it's own problems ... you would have to loop through all the controls in the page to do that ... which can be a performance issue if you have many ...

Comment: Also you have to be careful not to go inside usercontrols since the logicaltreehelper will by default.

Comment: Why a loop? In the XAML of the parent, why not give the UserControl element a name and directly reference it via the code behind. This way you can call your own Initialized sub. Maybe the name "Public Sub ParentInitialized()"

Also, I believe (but I'm not positive) WPF tracks initialized state via a flag. Once OnInitialized has been called the flag is set. Calling it a second time causes the flag to be checked and the sub returns. The event is not raised. Of course this would not affect your own custom initialize sub if you choose to create one.